# Txt file to 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am striving to meet the requirements of this community. I have bashed my head against this problem for ten hours or so. I rarely ask for help, so forgive me if I am not fully compliant.

I have been assigned to make a java code that will read a text file that is an ASCII image. The first line of the text file is the dimensions of the image, ignoring the first line. I am having a devil of a time filling the character array. When I use dummy text the program outputs an array of the correct size, but I can't get it to store the actual characters from the file. I'm absolutely certain that I am experiencing some 1D1OT errors, there's probably a lot of junk code. I've tried to clean it up, but the frustration from writing the file has been my main focus.

Also: yes this is absolutely a homework assignment. Full disclosure. I wouldn't be using an array for this task otherwise. However, the assignment isn't due for more than a week. I really don't want to be one of those individuals that want you to do their work for them.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Shell{

    private static String fileName = null;
    private static int imageHeight =0;
    private static int imageWidth=0;
    private static char[][] buffer = null;
    private static Scanner input;
    private static Scanner in;
    private static Scanner in2;
    private static Scanner inFile;

    /*
    FUNCTION NAME: Main ;
    INPUT: none.
    OUTPUT: a message to the user of this program, all of the
    prompts and a final display according to user specifications.
    PRECONDITIONS:  None.
    POSTCONDITIONS: Variables and calls made according to users input
                    output set to start on a new line.
    CALLERS: None.
    CALLEES: askPermission, getParameters(), getImage(), and doTileJob().

     */

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

    //in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.println("What file name would you like to print?");
    //String fileName = in.nextLine();
    //input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    boolean a = askPermission();
        if (a == true) { 
            while (a == true) {
                System.out.println("What is the name of the file you want printed?");
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                fileName = in.nextLine();
                new Scanner(new File(fileName));
                System.out.println(fileName);
                getParameters();
                buffer = new char[imageHeight][imageWidth];
                getImage();
                printImage();
                a = askPermission();}
        }
        //else if (a == false) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");

        //}

    }



    /*
    FUNCTION NAME: askPermission ;
    INPUT: none.
    OUTPUT: a message to the user of this program.
    PRECONDITIONS:  output set to start on a new line.
    POSTCONDITIONS: variable response has user's answer stored in it.
    CALLERS: the main program
    CALLES: None.

     */

    public static boolean askPermission()
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to print an image in a file?");
        System.out.println("If yes, type 'y'. If no, type 'n'");

        in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Ans = in2.nextLine();
        if (Ans.equals("y")){
        return true;}

        else {
        return false;
        }
    }


    /*
   FUNCTION NAME getParameters ;
   INPUT: the file name, number of tiles across and down.
   OUTPUT: message "Getting Image".
   PRECONDITIONS: the variable response has 'y' in it.
   POSTCONDITIONS: variables set with the values entered by user.
   CALLERS: the main program
   CALLEES: none
     */

    static void getParameters() throws FileNotFoundException
    {   
        inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        imageHeight = (inFile.nextInt());  
        imageWidth = (inFile.nextInt());

    }

    /*
    FUNCTION NAME: getImage ;
    INPUT:the file name and the height and width of the pattern to be made.
    OUTPUT: the message "Getting Image".
    PRECONDITIONS: array for image declared, the variables fileName, 
                   imageHeight and imageWidth set with proper values.  
    POSTCONDITIONS: the image is stored in the array.
    CALLERS: the main program
    CALLEES: none
     */
    public  static void getImage() throws FileNotFoundException
{   
    String string = "";
    input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        {
        for (int n = 0; n<(imageHeight);) 
        {  

            string = input.nextLine();
            char[] charArray = new char[n];
            string = string + input.nextLine();
            charArray = string.toCharArray();       
            System.out.println(charArray[n]);
            char q = charArray[n];
            buffer[n][0] = (q);


            for(int p = 1; p<(imageWidth); p++) 
            {

                char[] charArrayW = string.toCharArray();       
                char a = charArrayW[p];
                buffer[n][p] = (a);

            }
           n=n+1;
        }
    }
}








    /*
    FUNCTION NAME: printImage
    INPUT:the buffer with the image and the height and width of the
          pattern to be made
    OUTPUT: the patterns structured according to users input.
    PRECONDITIONS: All of the variables are set and pattern is stored in 'buffer'.
    POSTCONDITIONS: Output displayed according to users input.
    CALLERS: the main program
    CALLEES: none
     */
    //  This function uses for loops to display the images. The inner most for loop prints one line of the picture.


    public  static void printImage()
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<imageHeight; i++) {
            System.out.print (buffer[i][0]);
            //System.out.println();
            for(int j=0; j<imageWidth; j++) 
                System.out.print (buffer[i][j]);
                System.out.println();}
    }
    }
```

Right now it seems like I am so close. The problem I'm getting is that in getImage() I'm receiving a "No line found" exception at line 126. It prints a very small amount of the file, just a few characters on the first vertical line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your `getImage` method. First, you should skip the first line from the file which contains width/height. Second you are reading the line (call `input.nextLine()` twice per loop iteration), so effectively you need `2*imageHeight` lines. No wonder you cannot read them correctly. Next, you concatenate the `string` for some reason with previous string (`string = string + input.nextList()`). It's completely unnecessary. Next I see meaningless to extract `n-th` character from the line in `char q = charArray[n]` and print it. The `n` variable is the row number, while `charArray` indices correspond to the columns! Also no need to call `toCharArray()` on every nested loop iteration. Finally you need to close files using `try-with-resources` statement. Here's the fixed code:

```
public static void getImage() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String string = "";
    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName)))
    {
        input.nextLine(); // skip width/height
        for (int n = 0; n < (imageHeight);) {

            string = input.nextLine();
            char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();

            for (int p = 0; p < (charArray.length); p++) {

                char a = charArray[p];
                buffer[n][p] = (a);

            }
            n = n + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that immediately. My plan was to just increase the array by 1 height and then skip the first row of the array in the printing loop, but your solution is far more elegant. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm still getting a read error for the "string = input.nextLine();", is this because the input isn't scanning the file properly? Or have I left out a fileName reference?

Comment: Oh, so when you use "string.toCharArray();" it writes the whole line to the array? That makes way more sense. I've been trying to add character by character.

Comment: Okay, so it printed the image when I commented out the "string = input.nextLine();", but it didn't skip the next line. So there's something about that statement that's causing a "line not found" exception. It shouldn't be reassigning the input scanner, should it? Would using two scanners work?

Comment: Well, thank you so much for your help. I'm sorry if it appeared like I hadn't researched the problem, but I truly did. I am going to study the elements used in your code as to try to learn what I didn't already know. Again, thank you for your time, you must be a very generous soul to take notice of my nonsense. I hope you have a good day.

Comment: Yep, biggest 1D10T error possible. I failed to put the final line in the txt file.